# Which linux kernel options need to be enabled to support bluetooth low energy?

Tags: linux-kernel, bluetooth, bluez

Which are the mandatory and optional options?

Comment: The Linux kernel and bluez are two separate things. Which one do you mean? Please update your question to clear this up.

Comment: I have removed the part about bluez in the question details.